# Before me is stride

Tags: riddle

Before me is stride,
Paraded by pride.
After is hope,
Her possible scope.
I'm but a girl,
Who's fourth in the whirl.

What am I?

Comment: oh.. i love girls...:p ..Is your name april?

Comment: @manshu Why don't you answer the question instead of revealing your guess in a comment?

Comment: naah...answering a question is cumbersome. Commenting is easy. And it's not like you are in problem if you dont get the answer, is it?

Comment: @manshu It seems the spirit of this community is lost on you, but that's okay.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stride, paraded by pride

> perhaps a *march*?

Hope, her possible scope

> seems like *may* would fit, an auxiliary verb (and feminine name) that indicates possibility, a wish, or permission.

but a girl, who's fourth in the whirl

> *April* is another feminine name, and the fourth month of the year, falling after *March* and before *May*

Comment: see? I was right..:D :p

Comment: @manshu yes, but if you had posted it as an answer, like i did, you would have reaped those sweet, sweet imaginary internet points.

Comment: naah...i even shouldn't be on the puzzling community right now...gotta get my brain ready for the exams...

Comment: @manshu Good luck on the exams!